# EF querying on subset of collection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Course 
{    
   public int Id; 
   public string Title; 
   public string Description; 
   public ICollection<Tag> Tags;
}
public class Tag 
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
}
```

I have a Search method that takes a List of Tag, I want to return those Courses that contain all the Tags provided

```
public List<Course> SearchByTags(List<Tag> tags);
```

I came up with this, but it cant be translated into a sql query.

```
query= query.Where(kl => tags.All(t => kl.Tags.Contains(t)));
```

Is there a way of achieving this efficiently?

Comment: The first question is: does it even work? EF can't translate a list of objects like `tags` into SQL.

Comment: You're right this cant  translated into a proper query, so the new question is how to get this working.

Comment: So why not ask that in the first place? Also, did you try to find a solution in similar questions?

Comment: I  had a mock setup with in memory queryable. So that was my fault.
Searching constantly, but the complication seems to be that all the tags provided should be in the collection.

Comment: What version of EF are  you using?

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you intended to have a Many-to-Many relationship between Course and Tag, eg

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new HashSet<Tag>();
}
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new HashSet<Course>();
}
```

I found a couple of query forms that can be translated.  This is the best:

```
var qTags = from t in db.Set<Tag>()
            where tagIds.Contains(t.Id)
            select t;

var q = from c in db.Set<Course>()
        where qTags.All(t => c.Tags.Contains(t))
        select c;
```

Translates to

```
  SELECT [c].[Id], [c].[Description], [c].[Title]
  FROM [Course] AS [c]
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [Tag] AS [t]
      WHERE [t].[Id] IN (1, 2, 3) AND NOT (EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM [CourseTag] AS [c0]
          INNER JOIN [Tag] AS [t0] ON [c0].[TagsId] = [t0].[Id]
          WHERE ([c].[Id] = [c0].[CoursesId]) AND ([t0].[Id] = [t].[Id]))))
```

A translatable query that fetches all the Course.Id values that have all the tags is:

```
var q = from t in db.Set<Tag>()
        where tagIds.Contains(t.Id)
        from c in t.Courses
        group c by c.Id into byCourse
        where byCourse.Count() == tagIds.Count
        select new { id = byCourse.Key };
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I intended, but all my solutions where client side, by enforcing an AsEnumerable somewhere in the query